# How to get a form's data after the user submitted it with Spring MVC?

Tags: java, exception, spring-mvc, forms-authentication, java.lang.class

i am getting an error message:
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to com.crimetrack.business.Login

Login.java

```
public class Login {

    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private boolean loggedin;

    public Login(){};

    /**
     * @return the loggedin
     */
    public boolean isLoggedin() {
        return loggedin;
    }

    /**
     * @param loggedin the loggedin to set
     */
    public void setLoggedin(boolean loggedin) {
        this.loggedin = loggedin;
    }

    /**
     * @param userName
     * @param password
     */
    public Login(String userName, String password) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
    }

    /**
     * @return the userName
     */
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    /**
     * @param userName the userName to set
     */
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the password
     */
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    /**
     * @param password the password to set
     */
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

---

```
@Controller
public class AuthenticationController {

    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private Login login = new Login();

    String message = "Congrulations You Have Sucessfully Login";
    String errorMsg = "Login Unsucessful";

    @RequestMapping(value="login.htm")
    public ModelAndView onSubmit(Object command) throws ServletException {

        String userName = ((Login)command).getUserName();
        String password = ((Login)command).getPassword();

        login.setUserName(userName);
        login.setPassword(password);

        logger.info("Login was set");

        logger.info("the username was set to " + login.getUserName());
        logger.info("the password was set to " + login.getPassword());

        if (authenticationManager.Authenticate(login) == true){
            return new ModelAndView("main","welcomeMessage", message);
        }

        //return new ModelAndView("main","welcomeMessage", message);
        return new ModelAndView("login","errorMsg", "Error!!!");
    }

}
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: String userName = ((Login)command).getUserName();
String password = ((Login)command).getPassword();

These two lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution:

**JSP**

```
<form:form action="yourUrl" modelAttribute="login" method="POST">
<% ... %>
</form:form>
```

**Controller**

```
// your method that prints the form
public ModelAndView onGet(@ModelAttribute Login login) {
    // return ...
}

@RequestMapping(value="login.htm")
public ModelAndView onSubmit(@ModelAttribute Login login) {
    String userName = login.getUserName();
    String password = login.getPassword();
    // ...
}
```

**Explanation**

The annotation `@ModelAttribute` does exactly the same as `model.addAttribute(String name, Object value)`. For example, `@ModelAttribute Login login` is the same as `model.addAttribute("login", new Login());`.

That said, with the `onGet` method, you passing such an object to your view. Thanks to the attribute `modelAttribute="login"`, the tag `<form:form>` will look into the model's list of attributes to find one which name is `login`. If it doesn't find, an exception is thrown.

Then, that's the magic part: with the tag `<form:input path="userName" />`, Spring MVC will automatically set the property `userName` of the bean which is in the `modelAttribute="login"` attribute, i.e. in your case, `login`. If you had put something like `<form:input path="wtf" />`, it would have thrown an exception, because the bean `Login` doesn't have such a property.

So, finally, on your `onSubmit` method (thanks once again the to annotation `@ModelAttribute`), you can access to the `login` bean, previously autobinded by Spring MVC.

**Note**

I personally (almost) never use a `ModelAndView` instance, but proceed as follow:

```
// the methods can have the name you want
// not only onGet, onPost, etc. as in servlets

@RequestMapping("url1.htm")
public String loadAnyJsp(@ModelAttribute Login login) {
    return "path/to/my/views/login";
}

@RequestMapping("url2.htm")
public String redirectToAnotherController(@ModelAttribute Login login) {
    return "redirect:url1.htm";
}
```

The path to the JSP is specified within your web.xml file, for example:

```
...
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver" p:favorPathExtension="true" p:favorParameter="true" p:ignoreAcceptHeader="true" p:defaultContentType="text/html">
    <description>Depending on extension, return html with no decoration (.html), json (.json) or xml (.xml), remaining pages are decoracted</description>
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
            <entry key="html" value="text/html" />
            <entry key="action" value="text/html" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView" p:marshaller-ref="xstreamMarshaller" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="viewResolvers">
        <list>
            <bean id="nameViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver">
                <description>Maps a logical view name to a View instance configured as a Spring bean</description>
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" p:prefix="/WEB-INF/views/" p:suffix=".jsp" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
...
```

You should read [the doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) to get more information (cf. 16.5 Resolving views).

Comment: OK this worked but can you tell me cause i am not understanding how does the login class get the values the user inputs. This is abstract to me and i am making a lot of mistakes cause i don't understand how the pojos get set to the values the user inputs. Please explain this to me.

Comment: yes it did work, but when it comes to understanding how the pojo gets set with the values from the user UI i am lost i know it happens but i think i need an explanation as to exactly how spring does it.

Comment: OK great explanation i understand this a whole lot clearer now

Comment: just one more small question can you tell me when you would use the  ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,  HttpServletResponse response) method. I have used this method in other applications to handle users 'post' now i see spring uses an onGet(@ModelAttribute)

Comment: @dev_darin See the new edit. The way I explain is quite common and makes the development easier.

Comment: thank you very much this was a wonderful explanation you have cleared up most of my doubts

Answer (score 1):

In your 'onSubmit' method you are casting `command` to `Login`.

Apparently it is not.

Comment: I did a cast: Login login = (Login)command; and still same error

Comment: this is my application-servlet:

  
    <bean name="/login.htm" class="com.crimetrack.web.AuthenticationController">
      <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>               
    </bean>